# Call delegate (func/action) with generic argument in dynamic assembly

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to create dynamic assembly with generic class:

```cs
class TestClass<T> where T : new() {
  public T TestMethod() {
    return f();
  }

  private Func<T> f;
}
```

So, I created class, added generic argument, set constraints and created delegate like this:

```cs
var fieldType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(TArg); 
// TArg = testClassBuilder.DefineGenericParameters("T")[0];
```

Then using IL generator I tried to emit calling `Invoke` method:

```cs
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, fieldType.GetMethod("Invoke"));
```

But I get `NotSupportedException` on `GetMethod("Invoke")` call. So, how to call this delegate using `Emit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call `GetMethod` on `typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(TArg)`, because in this instance, `TArg` is a `GenericTypeParameterBuilder`, and the `Type` object returned by `MakeGenericType` doesn't know how to get the relevant methods.

Instead [use `TypeBuilder.GetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.getmethod?view=net-5.0#remarks) like this:

```cs
ilGenerator.Emit(
    OpCodes.Callvirt,
    TypeBuilder.GetMethod(
        typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(genParam),
        typeof(Func<>).GetMethod("Invoke")
));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll try and will give you reply